# Android Action_Call intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Am developing functionality in which i wanted to Intent.ACTION_DIAL.
Below is the code which i have tried so far.

```
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    String str = "tel:xxxxxxxxxx";                             callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(str));
                                    context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

However facing below two problems

1) if i tried to retrieve the imei number using "tel:*#06#" then it will open the device dialer with '*' only. "#06#" is not appearing there.

2) It asks the user to press call button. I dont want user to press the call button. is there any API which will allow me to directly execute "tel"*#06# kind of code from application itself.

EDITED:

I have tried below answer. its invoking dialer with "*#06#" but not showing the IMEI number of the device. if i press the same from device dialer and it showing IMEI number instantly.
All i want is to show the IMEI kind of codes from Application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);  
        String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");  
        String ussd = encodedHash + "06" + encodedHash;  
        startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",  
        Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)), 1);
```

and give this permission in android menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: Yes i have added the required permission and its working fine if i give cell number. My problem is that if i use something like     "tel:*#06#" then its not working.

Comment: I have followed the edited code its almost there but showing spiiner with "USSD code Running" and finally error message with "Connection proble or invalid MMI code.

Comment: try this String ussd ="*"+encodedHash + "06" + encodedHash i mean just add * before the code i hope the USSD which you are running  is invalid @Vishal

Comment: Yes i have followed the same. String ussd ="*"+encodedHash + "06" + encodedHash but its not showing IMEI number. Its just showing phones dialer with "*#06#" . IT is supposed to display IMEI number.

Comment: Well its working on Samsung 7 inch tab but not on Canvas HD 116. Any specific reason for that. I have used ACTION_DIAL intent.

Comment: It may be because of different versions , but i am not sure , if possible check with the other high end devices